# std::function internal memory organization and copies; passing reference vs value

Tags: c++, std-function

When a `std::function` is copied, are the code instructions it references copied as well?

An `std::function` is initialized via some form of callable, that points to executable code in some way (like a function pointer typically does). Now, when a function-object is copied, is this executable code runtime copied or internally referenced?
To rephrase the question: If one instance of `std::function` is copied, are there then multiple copies of the same compiled code instructions in memory?
Is `std::function` an object that actually stores the function code or is it more an abstraction for a function pointer?

The former would seem wasteful and I don't suspect it, but everything I found so far on the subject is either too vague, lacking or too specific for me to say for me for sure. For example

> When the target is a function pointer or a std::reference_wrapper, small object optimization is guaranteed, that is, these targets are always directly stored inside the std::function object, no dynamic allocation takes place. Other large objects may be constructed in dynamic allocated storage and accessed by the std::function object through a pointer. - [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function)

gives some hints about how it's done but seems still too vague and maybe is not related at all to this question, because of further abstractions inside of `std::function`.

**For context:** I am trying to refactor some bad C-ish code that maps input-events (keystrokes, mouse input and the like) to a certain behavior, which is executed upon a target data structure which can be interpreted by the program as more specific input that have semantic context other than than keystrokes (, aka keybindings). One can suspect that requirements of behaviours varies drastically.
This was previously implemented with lists of defines and numbers specifying input-event-ids, and hard-coded behavior, which was selected by switch-case. We quickly approach the border of where this intial way of doing it becomes unwieldly.
To get out of the defined lists to an expandable, declarative, object oriented and flexible design I consider higher order functions.
Especially since some behavior is quite simple and repeatedly needed (like for example the toggle of one value in the output data structure) other behaviors are more complex with multiple conditions attached, I'd like to declare some of the behavior statically, but still would like to be open to just assign some special lambda in some cases. Since I need to store behavior per input (key, mousebutton, mouse-axis, etc.) and potentially many copies of one certain behaviour type can be instantiated in one time for different sets of keybindings, I wonder if this behavior should be referenced, rather than stored by value. In the former case, fresh lambdas would need to be owned by the behavior structures, but statically declared behavior does not, which pragmatically would lead to some `shared_ptr` shenanigans. In the latter case, by value, this would not be an issue, but I wouldn't want multiple copies of for example the toggle behavior to cause too much redundant overhead instead.

Comment: std::function is an object, like any c++ object. Do you worry about copying code when you copy a vector?

Comment: A vector typically holds no callable instructions in a buffer, that were compiled.

Comment: Many execution environments do not support dynamic code generation (e.g. ROM, many phone app stores). Even those that do support it typically do not provide sufficient information to copy and relocate arbitrary code. C++ relies on the compiler to generate code at compile time. Instance data of course is copied frequently.

Comment: What do you mean with "the code instructions it references"? The executable is generated at compile time. At run-time there is only values being manipulated and passed around. I feel like something in that basic concept has been missed here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Note: the whole discussion below is a little simplified. AFAIK, none of it is wrong, but I did omit some details and edge cases and definitions and implementation stuff.)

The `std::function` does *not* copy any executable code. The executable code is always merely pointed to, by `std::function`. And when the `std::function` gets copied, the pointer gets duplicated (which is completely fine, because executable code is never freed either.) So far, there is no difference between a plain old function pointer and a `std::function`.

But that's not the whole story.

Contrary to function pointers, instances of `std::function` can carry around "state" as well as a pointer to the executable code, and the whole hubbub about `std::function` having to allocate/deallocate and copy/move data around is *about this extra state, not the function pointer*.

Suppose that you have code like this:

(And note that although I've used a lambda here, the following explanation would have been equally applicable for "functors" and "function objects" and "bind results" and other forms of callable things in C++, all except plain old function pointers.)

```
int x = 42, y = 17;
std::function<int()> f = [x, y] {return x + y;};
```

Here, `f` not only stores the pointer to the executable code for `return x + y;`, but it also has to remember the value of `x` and `y`. Since the amount of state that you can "capture" in this way is not limited, then - by definition - the `std::function` must allocate memory from the heap upon construction, and deallocate it, copy it and move it at appropriate times. Again, it is this extra "state" that gets copied, not the code.

Let's review: each `std::function` needs to be able to store at least a pointer to executable code, and 0 or more bytes of extra captured state. If there is no captured state, a `std::function` is essentially the same as a function pointer (although in practice, `std::function`s are usually implemented polymorphically and have other stuff in there.)

Some (most) implementations of `std::function` that I'm aware of employ an optimization that is called "Small Object Optimization". In these implementations, in addition to the space for the pointer to code, the `std::function` object has some more (fixed amount of) space inside its instance (i.e. as a member of its class, as opposed to somewhere else on the heap) and will use that area if the total number of bytes of the captured state would fit in there. This eliminates the heap allocation, which is important in some use cases and would balance out the additional memory used (when there is no or little state to capture.)

Comment: Like I wrote, I did not suspect instruction code to be copied, but the information around the subject is tricky. Your explanation adresses the confusion even better than my own answer, so I will accept this one.

Comment: For Visual C++, a look at the disassembly reveals, that the captures are stored on the stack and the same code address for the lambda is called. Even without captures, no inline expansion is used.

Answer (score 1):

I think the information in regarding the exceptions share some light:

> Does not throw if other's target is a function pointer or a std::reference_wrapper, otherwise may throw std::bad_alloc or any exception thrown by the constructor used to copy or move the stored callable object. [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function#Exceptions)

This seems to imply that every copy of the std::function copies the contained callable as well. For example, in case your function contains a lambda with a vector, that lambda and by result vector gets copied. The actual machine code that is linked to it, stays in the read-only part of your executable and won't be copied.

An update from [the c++20 standard draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf): 20.14.16.2.1  Constructors and destructor[func.wrap.func.con]

> function(const function& f);
>
> Postconditions: !*this if !f; otherwise, *this targets a copy off.target().
>
> Throws: Nothing iff’s target is a specialization ofreference_wrapperor
> a function pointer. Otherwise, may throwbad_allocor any exception
> thrown by the copy constructor of the stored callable object.
>
> [Note:
> Implementations should avoid the use of dynamically allocated memory
> for small callable objects for example, where f’s target is an object holding only a pointer or reference to an object and a member function pointer. — end note]

Comment: This would imply that if an std::function manages a callable, and it is a reference or a function pointer, that it does not manage the ressource itself, but in all other cases it does.

Comment: Where did that quote come from? It doesn’t sound right.

Comment: Even for the reference_wrapper, it manages the reference_wrapper class, though, that is a shallow reference to the actual callable. And for the function pointer, it also will copy the address to the function

Comment: @PeteBecker CppReference, a few lines below the quoted text from the question

Comment: While this certainly points to the answer of the question I would not consider it definite. Further it seems to manage the "target" callable by copy (if copied itself) and then the actual behavior regarding instruction code would be specified by that callable. Maybe I should update the question to that regard.

Comment: @PeteBecker I've found almost the same quote in the standard. See update

Comment: *"every copy of the std:: function copies the content as well"* - This is a bit misleading, since OP asked if *"the code instructions it references copied"*, I suggest explicitly saying that the instructions are not copied.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this was my original point. It seems that std::function does declare the behavior regarding instruction code itself, but the specific callable it manages does.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The latest update should reflect this.

Comment: Edit : ** std::function does not, specific callable does

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `std::function` does only manage one callable.
If copied, what happens to code is specified by the callable itself.

In a function pointer case, only a function pointer needs to be copied.

In a lambda or custom callable case this would be determined by the implementation of the copy of lambdas or any custom callable class.
These latter 2 typically can hold members of their own, outside of the reference to code. Therefore some space must be allocated by `std::function` to accomodate these cases. This is however misleading as it could seem `std::function` as allocating space for code. The management of instruction code seems to be done by the callable however this is done internally there.

In this context default behavior of typically used callables (like lambdas) when copied seems far more interesting for the intended question, but does seem to strech the posed question too far out of the bounds of the context of `std::function`.

I therefore would consider this question as solved as posed and deepen my knowledge about how lamdas are implemented especially in regards to how they are compiled and the compiled code referenced.

Comment: Even with a lambda, no code is copied; only the captures are copied. In general, in standard C++ there's no way to manipulate/copy the actual instructions, so copying a callable shouldn't copy instructions (unless the callable does some [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)ting).